# Set callback url for Facebook login button

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm starting to work with FB integration on my website and I've found that Facebook's documentation isn't that great.

I want to create a login button on my page and then handle the response on the server side but I cannot seem to find a good way to do that.

I'm using the  XFBML tag, but the only event I know of is the "onlogin" (which by the way, I cannot find in the documentation), which allows me to set a javascript function as callback, the problem there is that I would have to call FB.getLoginStatus to get the logged in info and then redirect the user to the page I want and also manually pass the logged in user's info in the query string.

e.g. Put this code on the onlogin callback function

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    window.location.replace('/Account/ProcessFbLogin?uid=' + response.session.uid ...');
  }
}
```

I think there should be a better way to do this, but I just cannot find it.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for " Facebook's documentation isn't that great."

Comment: neither is RenRen's =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way can be the [OAuth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) where you can specify the `redirect_uri` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

check out [SocialAuth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/)...super cool and easy to use!